# fwrite/fread for complex datatype numbers giving zero as result

Tags: c++, fwrite, fread, complex-numbers, complex-data-types

I've tried fwrite/fread for int, char and complex datatypes. They all worked well except complex. The read values of both the real and imaginary parts are all zero.

**Code:**

```
int main()
{
    typedef complex<float> cf;
    
    FILE *stream;
    stream = fopen("fread.out", "w+t");
    
    unsigned int n1 = 6;
    char *c1 = "this is a test";   
    cf cp1{2.0, 3.0};
    
    fwrite(&n1, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, stream);
    fwrite(c1, sizeof(char), strlen(c1), stream);
    fwrite(&cp1, sizeof(cf), 1, stream);
    fclose(stream);
    
    stream = fopen("fread.out", "r+t");
    unsigned int n2;
    char c2[20];
    cf cp2;
    
    fread(&n2, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, stream);
    fread(&c2, sizeof(char), strlen(c2), stream);
    fread(&cp2, sizeof(cf), 1, stream);
    
    fclose(stream);   
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
n2 = 6,c2 = this is a test, cp2 = 0.000000 + i*0.000000
```

Comment: Don't mix C and C++ is such way. If you want to use C++ features then use them to fullest. No C functions for I/O. Use `std::fstream`

Comment: Are the return values of each `fread` as expected? Also, `c2` is uninitialized, so `strlen(c2) >= sizeof c2` may be true, which is a problem.  What you want is a fixed-length field where all bytes are written (use `sizeof`, not `strlen`) or a way to determine the length of a dynamic-length field (e.g. write the length before the string, then read the length and use it to read the string).

Comment: `typedef complex<float> cf;` <- Not C

Comment: Logistically, were you using C, `fwrite(c1, sizeof(char), strlen(c1), stream);` does not write a *nul-terminating* character. When saving strings to a binary file you also have to write the length to the  file *before* writing the string so you can read the length and know how many characters follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a problem here:

```
 fread(&c2, sizeof(char), strlen(c2), stream);
```

strlen(c2) gives you garbage, because c2 is not initialized.
You should change c2 to c1 in this strlen function to make this example work.

For production ready code one should choose a more complex serialization technique, probably one of the existing solutions.